# Run exs file from within an exs file in elixir

Tags: scripting, elixir

I would like to run two elixir scripts, `first.exs` and `second.exs`.
I would like second to also run first. What would be a nice way to run this?

For example, the code could look something like this:

`first.exs`

```
IO.puts "first"
```

`second.exs`

```
IO.puts "second"
System.cmd("mix run first.exs")
```

And would output something like this:

```
mix run first.exs
first

mix run second
first
second
```

I would like to avoid using `System.cmd` though and use the `Mix` module if possible

Comment: You might also consider whether or not you truly need two separate `.exs` files.  It's simpler to deal with one file if possible. Just a suggestion, of course.

Comment: I personally would go with wrapping `first` and `second` code into Mix tasks. This is pretty straightforward and clean and mix tasks might naturally depend one on another.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`Code.eval_file`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Code.html#eval_file/2):

```
Code.eval_file "first.exs"
```

```
$ cat first.exs
IO.puts "first"
$ cat second.exs
IO.puts "second"
Code.eval_file "first.exs"
$ mix run second.exs
second
first
```

Comment: Huh – Dogbert seems uncharacteristically *helpful* on this site (of all places)!